# can we receive outbound message on localhost for debugging?

Tags: workflowoutboundmessage, workflowrule

I am new to salesforce.com, i created a outbound message for account and set workflow rule for create and edit.

my endpoint URL for outbound message is like http://localhost:2551/Listener.asmx

i am unable to receive out bound notification.

So, my question is can we use localhost or 127.0.0.1 as our Endpoint URL.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot use local host on salesforce. Your service had to be exposed on the internet. A quick and easy way to expose the local host to the internet would be using [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/) .

ngrok allows you to expose a web server running on your local machine to the internet. Just tell ngrok what port your web server is listening on.

Comment: Hi @mohith - is there any 'Salesforce best practice' over use ngrok or localtunnel? I assume that using these tools should really only be used for development / demo purposes.